# Chinese visa in Hong Kong

Tags: visas, china, hong-kong

On some web site I read that if I have a Chinese visa in Hong Kong and in case of it's expiration during stay in Hong Kong it's a serious violation of law and there is a fine up to $50,000 or 3 years in prison.

I did not find such information anywhere else. Normally, I do not need a visa at all to visit Hong Kong for 14 days.

Is this information about fines in case of expiration of Chinese visa correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainland China and Hong Kong have separate visa regimes. For example if you enter Hong Kong from the mainland, it will be considered as if you were leaving China and you would get an exit stamp.

Therefore it's unlikely that you would have any issue with a Chinese visa expiring whilst you are in Hong Kong. So unless you plan to re-enter mainland China on this visa afterwards, there won't be any problem.